# DrawImage resized image too small

Tags: c#, image, gdi+, image-resizing

When I draw an image using `Graphics.DrawImage` and draw it at a bigger size than the original image, it ends up being a bit too small. You can see this in the following picture:
[image]

The green lines shouldn't be visible and are not part of the image. Rather they get drawn behind the image and the image should cover them.

How can I draw an image with the exact right size?

**EDIT**: I draw the green part with the same rectangle I pass into the `DrawImage` call, with the exact dimensions of how big the image should be. So no flaw in my values (I think).

**EDIT 2**: I draw the green rectangle using `FillRectangle`, so no pen calculations need to be done. Also, I logged the values that I pass into the rectangle for both the image and the green fill, and the values are correct. It's just the image that's off. I will post code later, as I'm not at my computer at the moment.

**EDIT 3**: This is the code I use to render the images:

```cs
// This is for zooming
public readonly float[] SCALES = { 0.05f, 0.1f, 0.125f, 0.25f, 0.333f, 0.5f, 0.667f, 0.75f, 1.0f, 1.25f, 1.5f, 1.75f, 2.0f, 2.5f, 3.0f, 3.5f, 4.0f, 4.5f, 5.0f, 6.0f, 7.0f, 8.0f, 10.0f, 12.0f, 15.0f, 20.0f, 30.0f, 36.0f };
private int scaleIndex = 8;

protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);

    float ScaleFactor = SCALES[scaleIndex];

    e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = ScaleFactor < 1 ? InterpolationMode.Bicubic : InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;

    Image im = Properties.Resources.TSprite0;

    for (int y = 0; y < TilesVertical; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < TilesHorizontal; x++)
        {
            float sx = im.Width * ScaleFactor;
            float sy = im.Height * ScaleFactor;
            Point p = new Point((int)(-scrollPosition.X + sx * x), (int)(-scrollPosition.Y + sy * y));
            Size s = new Size((int)Math.Floor(sx), (int)Math.Floor(sy));

            // The green rectangle in the background should be the same size as the image
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Lime, new Rectangle(p, s));
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(im, new Rectangle(p, s), 0, 0, 16, 16, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        }
    }

    im.Dispose();
}
```

**EDIT 4**: Also note that the image seems to be cropped on the left and top instead of resized. Take a look at this comparison of the original image upscaled in Photoshop and then how GDI+ renders it:
[image]

Comment: I didn't downvote but I imagine the reason was that you didn't post any code.  It's very difficult to help without being able to look at your drawing code, edit it in and this becomes a good question.

Comment: @Jimi I use `FillRectangle`, so I don't use a pen.

Comment: @TaW Could you please explain your code? What do the values inside the points and the bitmap constructor mean?

Comment: @TaW Are you drawing the image at a bigger size than the original image dimensions?

Comment: I can confirm the issue for a scaling factor of 2f or greater. The offset is 1/2 of the scale.

Comment: I think I  found the reason. Let's delete all the confusing comments..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue happens when scaling to 2x or larger.

Looks like the whole problem is caused by the wrong default [PixelOffsetMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.pixeloffsetmode(v=vs.110).aspx).

> By offsetting pixels during rendering, you can improve render quality
>   at the cost of render speed.

Setting it to

```
g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.Half;
```

makes it go away for me.

Setting it to

```
g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
```

also works fine.

`Default`, `None` and `HighSpeed` cause the image to be rendered a little to the left and up.

Often you will also want to set `InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor`.

Comment: This seems to have been the issue! Thanks!

Comment: I can reproduce it also if `InterpolationMode` is set to `NearestNeighbor`. Other interpolation modes don't. I think I've never noticed it.