# How to draw image on Graphics without extra pixels at outer borders?

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, drawimage

This simple code gives me very bad result.

```
            Image global_src_img = Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath + "\\src.png");
            Image src_img = ((Bitmap)global_src_img).Clone(new Rectangle(160, 29, 8, 14), PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            src_img.Save(Application.StartupPath + "\\src_clonned.png", ImageFormat.Png);
            Bitmap trg_bmp = new Bitmap(100, 100);
            Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(trg_bmp);
            gfx.FillRectangle(new Pen(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0)).Brush, 0, 0, trg_bmp.Width, trg_bmp.Height);
            gfx.DrawImageUnscaled(src_img, (trg_bmp.Width / 2) - (src_img.Width / 2), (trg_bmp.Height / 2) - (src_img.Height / 2));
            gfx.Dispose();
            trg_bmp.Save(Application.StartupPath + "\\trg.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

It clones part of the big image with letters and writes it to another image.
Written image has extra pixels at outer borders that does not present in source image same as in cloned image.
How to avoid it?

This is cloned image (`src_clonned.png`) that later will be drawn on graphics.
[image]

This is saved resulting image (`trg.png`).
[image]

Comment: Probably a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50419325/drawimage-resized-image-too-small/50425266#50425266)

Comment: Did you try saving in .bmp format? Maybe just image compression artifacts you experience.

Comment: @PepitoSh - I didn't, since I need it to be in PNG, but PNG is lossless format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw directly on bitmap to avoid any pixels modifications with this:

```
public static void DrawImgOnImg(Image src, Bitmap trg, int x, int y)
{
    for (int i = x; i < x + src.Width; i++)
        for (int j = y; j < y + src.Height; j++)
        {
            Color src_px = ((Bitmap)src).GetPixel(i - x, j - y);
            trg.SetPixel(i, j, src_px);
        }
}
```