# Picturebox adds undesired gradient to stretched images (bug?)

Tags: c#, bitmap, image-resizing

PictureBox seems to be adding a gradient to stretched images.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(2, 2, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
    pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
    pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
}
```

Here is the strange result, where this gradient comes from? Is this a PictureBox bug?

[image: Destroyed image by picturebox bug]

Comment: I think Picturebox will always use high-speed PixelOffsetMode internally; you would want Half but won't get it. So if you are serious you need to create the stretched bitmap in code. One could call it a bug, but really your code makes not a lot of sense, does it?

Comment: My code is for demonstration purpose. It makes a lot of sense, since you could notice the effect. Couldn't you?

Comment: There was no real need to demostrate anything as the effect is well-known. Basically it is antialiasing. Both Picturebox internal drawing and DrawImage mix a pixel with its right&bottom neighbours. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50419325/drawimage-resized-image-too-small/50425266?s=1|38.9375#50425266) for a __similar__ effect. It is a quirk but no real bug as PictureBox is not meant to display 2x2 pixels. Therefore it is optimized for speed rather than accuracy. - As for symmetry: There is symmetry on the grid level but not on the pixel level. Can be confusing sometimes..

Comment: So you assume everything you know is well-known and ppl should not ask it here. For me this effect is undesired and it is also noticed in larger image, I used a small one to make a point.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug, if you are zooming into images you will get the same effect. It is used to get images smooth.
What you are doing is basically zooming into your bitmap, beacuse your bitmap only has a size of 2x2 pixels.

Comment: You are kind of right, I noticed that it is related to the interpolation mode. Overwriting it to nearestneighborhood using a derived picturebox class, the effect is gone. Even so it should look symmetric, I guess.

Comment: @Pedro77 The scaling has options of how it does smooth-scaling, and the default simply has the side effect that the edges get interpolated with missing data that the framework fills in on its own. There may be smooth scaling options that don't give this effect.