# Resize (downsize) rounded image borders cut

Tags: c#, interpolation, image-resizing, system.drawing

I want to resize an image that has a round shape, to a very low size.

For example this one:

[image: round image]

I tried to use the built-in System.Drawing rescale functions GetThumbnailImage, and also tried some InterpolationMode (HighQualityBilinear, HighQualityBicubic), but the resulting image always has the borders cut, for instance:

[image: round image downsized]

Notice the sharp lines at the right and bottom.

The result I would like to obtain instead is:

[image: round image downsized]

The difference is subtle, but it's worth it, and I can't find how to get it.

Note: The desired resulting image was obtained with this website: http://www.online-image-editor.com

Comment: a) we need to see the code you use. b) there is a Graphics property PixelOffsetMode. Set it to PixelOffsetMode.Half; - See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50419325/drawimage-resized-image-too-small/50425266#50425266)

Comment: Thank you very much TaW. This property solved the problem :)