# How to draw an image to whole a rectangle and not related to background

Tags: c#, image, graphics, image-resizing

I'm using `Graphics.DrawImageUnscaledAndClipped` to draw an image with my specific size, But it doesn't fill the rectangle properly or not related to the background.
For example I have an image with dimensions 57x43 and I want to fill my image by stretching it to my image with dimensions 240x240:

Sample code:

```
var image = Image.FromFile(mySourceImageFile);
var bmp = new Bitmap(240, 240);
var rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
{
    // ... some other codes
    g.Clear(Color.Aqua); // I use this to highlight whole image
    // ... some other codes
    g.DrawImageUnscaledAndClipped(image, rect);
    // ... some other codes
}

bmp.Save(myDestinationImageFile);
```

*My source image file:*
[image: My 57x43 Jpeg file]

*My destination image file:*
[image]

I should add that in my destination image file I have 5 pixel lines at bottom and 4 lines at right those affected by the background that is not expected!
How can I draw an image or a clipped image to fill my rectangle without getting affected by its current background?

I should also add that this is a part of my creating destination image and I know that for just resizing I can use `Bitmap(image, w, h)`.
And same result with using `g.DrawImage(new Bitmap(image, 240, 240), 0, 0);`

Comment: It appears [I was mistaken](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8072003/3181933) in what it does.

Comment: Try to set `Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.Half;`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50419325/drawimage-resized-image-too-small/50425266?s=1|49.1824#50425266)

Comment: @TaW tnx, But with `PixelOffsetMode.Half` or `PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality`; background affected yet but with 2 pixel lines in each side!.

Answer (score 0):

I found to ignore background I can set [`CompositingMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.compositingmode?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Drawing_Graphics_CompositingMode) to [`CompositingMode.SourceCopy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.compositingmode?view=netframework-4.7.2).

> **CompositingMode.SourceCopy**
>   Specifies that when a color is rendered, it overwrites the background color.

So my best try with using it is:

```
var image = Image.FromFile(mySourceImageFile);
var bmp = new Bitmap(240, 240);
var rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
{
    g.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;

    // And some other settings to improve quality
    g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
    g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
    g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
    g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;

    g.Clear(Color.Aqua); // I use this to highlight whole image
    // ... some other codes
    g.DrawImageUnscaledAndClipped(image, rect);
    // ... some other codes
}

bmp.Save(myDestinationImageFile);
```

*But with this solution borders of image sense blurred!!!*
[image]

**Update:**
A really bad hacky way to have a better effects can be this - not recommended -:
using a `tempBmp` that is bigger than original image with some repeated parts and use it instead of original image in resizing, something like this:

```
var image = Image.FromFile(mySourceImageFile);
var bmp = new Bitmap(240, 240);
var tempBmp = new Bitmap(image.Width + 4, image.Height + 5);

using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(tempBmp))
{
    g.DrawImage(image, 0, 0);
    g.DrawImage(image, 4, 0);
    g.DrawImage(image, 0, 5);
    g.DrawImage(image, 4, 5);
    g.DrawImage(image, 2, 0);
    g.DrawImage(image, 2, 1);        
    g.DrawImage(image, 0, 2);
    g.DrawImage(image, 1, 2);
    g.DrawImage(image, 4, 2);
    g.DrawImage(image, 3, 2);        
    g.DrawImage(image, 2, 5);
    g.DrawImage(image, 2, 4);
    g.DrawImage(image, 2, 3);
    g.DrawImage(image, 2, 2);
}

using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
{
    // ... some other codes
    g.Clear(Color.Aqua); // I use this to highlight whole image
    // ... some other codes
    var imageRect = new Rectangle(2, 2, image.Width, image.Height);
    var drawRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
    g.DrawImage(tempBmp, drawRect, imageRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    // ... some other codes
}

bmp.Save(myDestinationImageFile);
```

**And my destination image file is:**
[image: My destination image file]

So, I'm waiting for a better solution ;).