# WinForms: Edge pixels get cut in half when using Graphics.DrawImage

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm making a sprite editor for myself because I've found every other available option unsatisfactory. I decided to use C# and WinForms because that seemed like the simplest option to make a utility program. To create the canvas on which I'll edit sprites, I made a custom class that inherits from `UserControl`.

Up to that point everything worked great, but then I added the ability to zoom in and out. It works reasonably well, except for the fact that the top and left edge of my image appear cut off at the halfway point.

[image: Notice how the edge pixels appear "cut in half"]

Here is the `OnPaint` class method which draws the image.

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);

    RectangleF drawArea = new RectangleF(offset.X, offset.Y, sprite.Width * zoom, sprite.Height * zoom);

    e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = (zoom >= 1)? InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor : InterpolationMode.Default;
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(31, 0, 0, 0)), drawArea);
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(sprite, drawArea);
}
```

`sprite` is a `Bitmap` instance, `offset` is a `PointF`, and `zoom` is a `float`.

The fact that `drawArea` is a `RectangleF` seems to have no effect, and using a regular `Rectangle` yields identical results. I also tried flooring `offset.X` and `offset.Y` but that didn't improve the results.

What is causing the image to be drawn this way, and what alternatives do I have for drawing my sprite to the screen the correct way?

Comment: Have you tried different InterpolationModes?

Comment: Yes, I’ve tried other ones and they all seem to have a similar problem, though less apparent due to the blurryness.

Comment: You may need to change the [PixelOffsetMode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50419325/drawimage-resized-image-too-small/50425266#50425266)

Comment: Yep, sure enough I needed to make sure it was set to `Half`.

Answer (score 1):

TaW's suggestion was correct, I needed to make sure the `Graphics.PixelOffsetMode` was set to `Half`.

This is the code that produces the correct result:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);

    RectangleF drawArea = new RectangleF(offset.X, offset.Y, sprite.Width * zoom, sprite.Height * zoom);

    if (zoom >= 1)
    {
        e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
        e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.Half;
    }
    else
    {
        e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.Default;
        e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.Default;
    }

    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(31, 0, 0, 0)), drawArea);
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(sprite, drawArea);
}
```